# Корректное изменение состояния в redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать следующий момент:
При авторизации в приложении я получаю нужные данные с сервера: название магазина, описание, телефон и прочее. Эти данные храню в редюсере компонента Auth и сразу после авторизации они отображаются шапке личного кабинета. Кроме этого у меня есть компонент "О магазине". Туда точно так же я вывожу данные из state auth. 
Сам initialState в auth такой:

```
const initialState = {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    phone: null,
    address: null,
    text: null,
    authStatus: true
}
```

В компоненте About я могу изменить данные и отправить их изменение на сервер.

```
class About extends React.Component {
    state={
        shopFormControls: {
            name:{
                value: this.props.shopName,
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Название магазина',
                valid: true,
                touched: false,
                validation: {
                    required: false
                }
            },
            about: {
                value:  this.props.text,
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Описание',
                valid: true,
                touched: false,
                validation: {
                    required: false
                }
            },
            phone: {
                value: this.props.phone,
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Номер телефона',
                valid: true,
                touched: false,
                validation: {
                    required: false
                }
            },
            address: {
                value:  this.props.address,
                type: 'text',
                label: 'Адрес магазина',
                valid: true,
                touched: true,
                validation: {
                    required: false,
                    minLength: 6
                }
            }
        }
    }

    onChangeHandler =(event, controlName) =>{
        const shopFormControls = {...this.state.shopFormControls};
        const control = {...shopFormControls[controlName]}

        control.value = event.target.value
        control.touched = true
        shopFormControls[controlName] = control

        let isFormValid = true

        Object.keys(shopFormControls).forEach(name =>{
            isFormValid = shopFormControls[name].valid && isFormValid
        })
        this.setState({
            shopFormControls,
            isFormValid
        })
    }
    changeHandler = () =>{
        this.props.changeShop(
            this.state.shopFormControls.name.value,
            this.state.shopFormControls.about.value,
            this.state.shopFormControls.phone.value, 
            this.state.shopFormControls.address.value,
            this.props.token
        )
    }

    submitHandler = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    changeForm = () => {

        this.setState({
            formType: !this.state.formType
        })
    }
    renderInputs() {
        return Object.keys(this.state.shopFormControls).map((controlName, index) =>{
            const control = this.state.shopFormControls[controlName]
            return(
                <Input 
                    key={controlName + index}
                    type={control.type}
                    value={control.value}
                    valid={control.valid}
                    touched={control.touched}
                    label={control.label}
                    shouldValidate={!!control.validation}
                    errorMessage={control.errorMessage}
                    onChange={event=> this.onChangeHandler(event, controlName)}
                />
            )
        })

    }
    render(){


        return(
            <div className={classes.Footer}>
                <h1>О Магазине</h1>
                <div>
                <form className={classes.shopAbout} onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                {this.renderInputs()}

                <input type="submit" onClick={this.changeHandler} value="Сохранить"/>
                </form> 


                </div>
            </div>
        )

        }


    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
        return {
            changeShop: (shopName, aboutShop, phone, adress, token) => dispatch(changeShop(shopName, aboutShop, phone, adress,token))
        }
        }

        function mapStateToProps(state){
            return{
                shopName: state.auth.user,
                phone: state.auth.phone, 
                token: state.auth.token,
                address: state.auth.address,
                text: state.auth.text
            }
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(About)
```

Соответственно changeShop у меня находится в файле с экшенами, которые я создать для компонента about.
Т.е. изначально я получаю состояния которые хранятся в auth и передаю их внутрь экшенов about. Там делаю отправку на сервер и на серваке обновляю пользовательские данные.
Но при таком раскладе логично что данные которые хранятся в Auth не обновляются. Т.е. как я понимаю, мне надо при успешном экшене в About вызвать функцию в экшенах Auth которая обновить мне состояние приложения в нем. Как это правильнее сделать? Впервые сам пытаюсь сделать нечто вроде crm и боюсь пойти не в ту сторону. Сама структура стора выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем краткий вариант вопроса: как изменить state в auth при выполнении экшена в changeShop?

Answer (score 0):

1) Можешь в компоненте Auth вызвать хук UseEffect и в массив зависимость добавить данные, которые обязательно должны изменится. И если данные поменялись запросить их с сервера.

Пример:
`useEffect(() => {
  getData()
 }, [dataFromAboutState])`

2) Можно создать ещё один action в Auth и в reducer добавить switch если сработал экшен записать в Auth данные из About

Пример:

```
const DATA_WAS_UPDATE = 'DATA_WAS_UPDATE'

const updateAction = (newData) => ({
  type: DATA_WAS_UPDATE,
  payload: {
    newDataOne,
    newDataTwo,
    newDataThree
  }
})

const reducerInAuth = (state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  ...тут твои кейсы
    case DATA_WAS_UPDATE: 
      return {
      ...state,
      oldDateOne: action.payload.newDateOne,
      oldDateTwo: action.payload.newDateTwo
      oldDateThree: action.payload.newDateThree
    }
  }
}
```

Лучше ещё навесить проверку ответ от сервера статус 200? Что бы не вышло, что на сервере, что-то случилось, а данные в state поменялись.